# Javascript value assign sibling

Tags: javascript, siblings

I'm troubleshooting a new wordpress theme. And my investigation guided me to this situation (.js code, simplified):

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
     $(".thumbnail-quantity ").bind('mouseleave',function() {   
        // Get values from input box
        var new_qty = $(this).val();

        $(this).val( new_qty );
        $(this).siblings( ".button" ).attr( "data-quantity", new_qty );
    }); 
});
```

And there is the html code where it is invoked (same system, two different wordpress with woocommerce themes)

Old theme, where it nicely works:
(by "works", i mean - 'data-quantity' on "add_to_cart_button" actually changes, when i move mouse out of the +/- buttons of input name "thumbnail-quantity")

```
<input name="thumbnail-quantity" class="thumbnail-quantity quantity" min="3" value="3" step="1" "="" type="number">
<a data-quantity="3" href="/?add-to-cart=678" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="678" data-product_sku="" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">add to cart</a>
```

New theme, where works only $(this).val (new_qty)

```
<span class="price">
<span class="amount">0.35€</span></span>
<input name="thumbnail-quantity" class="thumbnail-quantity quantity" min="3" value="3" step="1" "="" type="number">
<div class="add-to-cart-button">
<a data-quantity="3" href="/?add-to-cart=678" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="678" class="add_to_cart_button product_type_simple button alt-button small clearfix">add to cart</a>
</div>
```

Whith this html code here - i see only changes on 'input name "thumbnail-quantity"', but not on the button.

My bet - it's 'siblings' that makes unable to find it's "button-brother".

What should i change in the .js so it would find the button and change it's value?
(i can't change the theme in some way.. it's too complicated)

Comment: Its not entirely clear what your problem is, could you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate?

Comment: Also, both your `input` elements have this weird `"=""` - is that intentional?

Comment: `$(this).next().children('.button').attr(...` ?

Comment: Jamiec - it's on both old an new themes.. so maybe it's not the case.. and i can't find where it starts, anyway ;)

Comment: Abhitalks - thank a lot. Your guess was the closest. actually solved it with:  $(this).siblings().last().children(".button").attr( "data-quantity", new_qty );

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).siblings( ".button" )` in this case is looking for ".button" elements on the same level where ".thumbnail-quantity" is placed.

But in your new theme ".button" element is put inside ".add-to-cart-button" div.

Place it outside the div like this:

```
<input name="thumbnail-quantity" class="thumbnail-quantity quantity" min="3" value="3" step="1" "="" type="number">
<a data-quantity="3" href="/?add-to-cart=678" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="678" class="add_to_cart_button product_type_simple button alt-button small clearfix">add to cart</a>
```

or alter jQuery to look inside the div:

```
$(".add-to-cart-button").find( ".button" ).attr( "data-quantity", new_qty );
```

Comment: While you're probably right with your assessment, it's safe to assume there may be more than one `.add-to-cart-button` elements, so you should probably tie this to the quantity being changed using some combination of `siblings('.add-to-cart-button')` or `next('.add-to-cart-button')`

Comment: Thanks, Pavlo, Jamiec! It moved forward this syntax amost works: 

$(this).next( '.add-to-cart-button' ).attr( "data-quantity", new_qty );

but it changes the attribute of the div "add-to-cart-button", not the a href which belongs to this div.

Actually it's no the "button" itself - it's in a <a href=> where i have attribute "data-quantity".

So, can you alter syntax so it would change the following chain: this -> div add-to-cart-button -> a href - >property "data-quantityf"?
Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: Try this one:
`$(this).next( ".add-to-cart-button" ).find( ".button" ).attr( "data-quantity", new_qty );`